# OpenGL Normal transformation in shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, lwjgl, normals

I am trying to create some basic lighting shaders in LWJGL. Everything seems to be working except that when I change the rotation of the camera, the lighting changes. I think it is because of the rotation of the normals being messed up as well when I rotated the camera.

Here is my original Vertex Shader:

```
uniform vec3 lightDir;
varying vec3 normal;

void main()
{       
    normal = gl_NormalMatrix*gl_Normal;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

My Fragment Shader:

```
varying vec3 normal;

void main(){
    vec3 color = vec3(1,1,1);
    vec3 lightDir = vec3(1,1,0);
    float inten = 1;
    color = color*dot(normal, lightDir)*inten;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1);

}
```

To transform the camera I used:

```
public static void applyTranslations() {
    glPushAttrib(GL_TRANSFORM_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glRotatef(pitch, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(yaw, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(roll, 0, 0, 1);
    glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z);
    glPopAttrib();
}
```

I realized that this method of transforming the camera might be actually changing the model while the camera remained static, which would have messed up the normals, so I tried to input a uniform matrix containing the model's rotation to transform the normals, but that doesn't seem to work either. Now the entire model is black. (It was working before, except the rotation.)
I used this to pass the changes to the Shader:

```
Vector3f scale, rot, trans;
Matrix3f modelMatrix = new Matrix3f();
modelMatrix.setIdentity();
scale = new Vector3f(1,1,1);
rot = new Vector3f(xRot,yRot,zRot);
trans = new Vector3f(x,y,z);

Matrix4f.scale(scale, modelMatrix, modelMatrix);
Matrix4f.translate(trans, modelMatrix, modelMatrix);
Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rot.z), new Vector3f(0,0,1), modelMatrix, modelMatrix);
Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rot.y), new Vector3f(0,1,0), modelMatrix, modelMatrix);
Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rot.x), new Vector3f(1,0,0), modelMatrix, modelMatrix);

FloatBuffer modelBuff = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9);
modelMatrix.store(modelBuff);

int loc = ARBShaderObjects.glGetUniformLocationARB(e.m.shader.programID, "modelMatrix");
ARBShaderObjects.glUniformMatrix4ARB(loc, false, modelBuff);
```

And then I changed my vertex shader to:

```
uniform vec3 lightDir;
uniform modelMatrix;
varying vec3 normal;

void main()
{       
    normal = modelMatrix*gl_Normal;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

Is this what I should be doing the create and pass transformation matrices? Also is there another way to rotate the camera without using glRotatef()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vec3 lightDir = vec3(1,1,0)` is constant while `normal` is transformed every time the camera changes.

To prevent this make sure `lightDir` and `normal` are in the same space. Compute the `dot` before transforming `normal` or, transform `lightDir` by `gl_NormalMatrix` then compute the `dot`.

In addition to the effect you want to achieve you have an issue in the fragment shader:  `normal` is not normalized. This is because a linear interpolation of unit vectors won't always produce a unit vector.

What you should do is something like:

```
color*dot(normalize(normal),  transform_to_same_space(lightDir))*inten;
```

Some minor issues in the second part:

You're declaring `modelMatrix` without a type.

You cannot transform `vec3` with a 4x4 matrix. You can pad `gl_Normal` with a 0 since it's a vector or cast down the matrix to `float3x3`.

You're using `Matrix4f.scale` with `Vector3f(1,1,1)` and the translation won't affect vectors so `modelMatrix` is orthonormal.
However, in the general case you should transform `gl_Normal` with the transposed inverse of `modelMatrix`.